# spring batch before step not getting called, need step execution context

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

In my spring batch workflow configuration I have item writer as follows:

```
@Bean
@Scope(value = "step", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)
public ItemWriter<Price> skippedItemWriter(@Value("#{stepExecution.executionContext}") ExecutionContext executionContext) {
    return new SkippedItemWriter(executionContext);
}


public class SkippedItemWriter implements ItemWriter<Price>, StepExecutionListener {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = getLogger(SkippedItemWriter.class);

    private final ExecutionContext executionContext;
    private StepExecution stepExecution;

    public SkippedItemWriter(final ExecutionContext executionContext) {
        this.executionContext = executionContext;
    }

    @Override
    public void write(List<? extends Price> items) {

        if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(items)) {
            return;
        }
        /blah 
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        LOGGER.info("in beforeStep");
        this.stepExecution = stepExecution;
    }

    @Override
    public ExitStatus afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

my before step and after step are not getting called.

the beans must be step scoped.

I am trying to get hold of the publish count which I set in previous steps:

```
ExecutionContext context = stepContribution.getStepExecution().getJobExecution().getExecutionContext();
context.putInt((PUBLISH_COUNT.name()), 0);
```

I have tried returning `SkippedItemWriter()` instead of `ItemWriter<T>` but I get another proxy error.

I should add SkippedItemWriter is part of composite writer:

```
@Bean
@Scope(value = "step", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)
public ItemWriter<Price> compositeWriter() {
    CompositeItemWriter<Price> itemWriter = new CompositeItemWriter<>();
itemWriter.setDelegates(Arrays.asList(
              skippedItemWriter(null)));

        return itemWriter;   }
```

Comment: You need to change the return type to `SkippedItemWriter` else Spring won't detect it as a `StepExecutionListener`.

Comment: I tried but it didnt work. I should add this particular writer is delegate as part of a composite writer that returns ItemWriter

Comment: Then you need to manually register it as a listener on your step, unless that delegate is also a `StepExecutionListener` which can delegate to its writers.

Comment: can you pls show an example and how ? my writer implements StepExecutionListener. I already add a listener ... .`listener(promoteContextListener())` with keys

Comment: Your writer implements that the composite doesn't and the composite is what the step sees not your own implementation. Hence you need to register your `skippedItemWriter` manually as a listener to your step.

Comment: my skipedItemWriter requies 2 args passed to constructor now so when I do .listener(new SkippedItemWriter() these dependencies are not there in step method

Comment: Please read. You should register the same instance as a listener as you are injecting into the composite writer.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that since your `SkippedItemWriter` is a delegate of a composite item writer, it is not automatically registered as a listener and this should be done manually. Here is an excerpt from the [Intercepting Step Execution](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.3.x/reference/html/step.html#interceptingStepExecution) section of the docs:

```
If the listener is nested inside another component, it needs to be explicitly
registered (as described previously under "Registering ItemStream with a Step").
```

So you need to explicitly register the `SkippedItemWriter` as a listener in your step.

Comment: Can you have multiple listeners in your step? I am already passing one executionpromotionlistener. Secondly, can you pass null as Args if the constructor of SkippedItemWriter takes params?

Comment: Yes you can have multiple listeners. `StepBuilder#listener` methods add listeners to a list.  Why do you need to pass `null`? In your example, you don't need to pass the `ExecutionContext` as parameter to the constructor of `SkippedItemWriter`, you can get the execution context from the `StepExecution` field.

Comment: my step adds the listener as follows:  `.writer(compositeWriter()).listener(promoteContextListener()).listener(new SkippedItemWriter(dep1, dep2))` but skippedItemWriter has two constructor args (dep1, dep2) which I don't really want to instance and pass here.

Comment: How is that related to the issue here? You have a bean that you want to register as a step listener so that its `beforeStep` and `afterStep` methods are called as expected. The answer to this question in your case is to manually register this bean in the step as a listener. Now how the dependencies of this bean are injected is a different story. What I can tell you is that injecting the execution context with SpEL and passing it to the constructor is not necessary because you can get the execution context from the StepExecution instance injected in your writer via `beforeStep`.

Comment: If you have other dependencies, you need to find a way to inject them into your bean, either manually or via Spring DI mechanisms. But again, that's another issue.

Comment: thanks, I removed ExecutionContext being passed. But yes, SkippedItemWriter has other dependencies which I am instantiating in the `public ItemWriter<Price> skippedItemWriter()` method itself.

Comment: ok, good to know. If the answer helped, please accept it. Thank you.